# List all fields in an elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I get a list of all the fields that are present in an index (i.e. fields that occur in indexed documents, not just in the mapping)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting with 1.3 you have the [_field_names](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/mapping-field-names-field.html) meta field.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "Field names": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_field_names", 
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This no longer works with 5.x See: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22576

Comment: Yes, @dezhi's answer is the correct one with ElasticSearch 5.2+

Answer (score 21):

**Explanation:**

Don't think there is any way to do exactly that.  But since everything in the index automatically gets thrown in the mapping, we know that the mapping contains at least every field in the index.  From there, you can loop through each field in the mapping and run a count on the number of results in the index that have that field.  If the count is more than 0, then that field exists; if the count is 0, then that field is not part of the index.  Since we know that every field in the index will exist in your mapping, this should cover all possibilities.

**Some example API calls:**

```
# Get the mapping
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/_mapping?pretty'

# Count a field
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/_count' -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "exists" : { "field" : "name_from_mapping" }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

**Documentation:**

- [`GET` mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html)
- [count API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html)
- [exists filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-filter.html)

Comment: Please note, that with my answer you will have to throw some code (or do manual labor) to actually determine which fields exist in your index..this is more of a theory/explanation/resource to get your started

Comment: Agreed. For the 2nd part of the solution – extracting the field list from the `json` response – perhaps the [elasticsearch-head:metaData.js](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head/blob/bee08506a964c1bff32c7be9c0b219a728f2704d/src/app/data/metaData.js) could be a source of inspiration.

Answer (score 19):

In current(5.2) version, you can use the mapping API to get all the field names:

```
GET index_name/_mapping?pretty
```

please refer to the [official document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the list of field names using SQL query

**Example**

```
GET _sql?format=txt
{
  "query": "DESC index_name"
}
```

**Output**

```
                        column                        |     type      |    mapping    
------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------------
description                                           |VARCHAR        |text           
description.autosuggest                               |VARCHAR        |text           
description.keyword                                   |VARCHAR        |keyword        
address                                               |STRUCT         |object
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone's using elasticsearch-py, this is a fast solution to this problem:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es_client = Elasticsearch("http://localhost:9200")
index_name = "index_foo"

fields_mapping = es_client.indices.get_mapping(index_name)
```

(this is @dezhi's analogous answer, but in python)

Answer (score -1):

I might consider creating an "elasticsearch-index-fieldlist" plugin, similar to https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-index-termlist, if there is really no straightforward way to get at the list of fields present in an index...

Comment: did you create a plugin / solution for this issue? thanks